# Unable to Create New Schema when Previous does not exists

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

This is my Logic for inserting new data for an expense tracking App in Node JS.

My Query is the function createNewData() never executes. If a previous UserData Schema on particular date exists then this code can update it with no Problem.

BUT if UserData Schema does not exists the code is not being able to create a new one.

Should I use something other than UserData.findOne, I had already used findOneAndUpdate() and exists() but nothing works. I am new with Mongoose kindly help

```
app.post("/insert",(req,res)=>{
  const username = req.cookies.username;
  const Date = now.toLocaleDateString("en-Uk");
  const Amount = req.body.value;


  function createNewData(){
    const userData = new UserData({
      email:username,
      date:Date,
      amount: Amount
    });
  
    userData.save((err)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }else{
        console.log('newdatasaved');
        res.redirect("/")
      }
    });
    User.findOneAndUpdate({email:username},{$push:{data:userData._id}},(err)=>{
      if(err){
        console.log('cant push');
      }else{
        console.log('pushed data');
      }
    });
  }

  UserData.findOne({email:username,date:Date},(err,found)=>{
    if(err){
      createNewData();
      console.log('cant find on particular date new created');

    }else{
      if(found){
        let a = Number(found.amount);
        let b = Number(Amount)+a;
        UserData.findOneAndUpdate({email:username,date:Date},{$set:{amount:b}});
        console.log('updated in existing');
        res.redirect("/");
      }

    }
    
  })
 
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a separate variable

```
let xyz = User.findOne({..conditions}).exec();
```

and then using `if` , `else` statement helped

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).